# Display username in the input (text) in my Angular 2 app

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular 2 app that displays the username in the text input as a text. What I do is to get user from my component using `userService` and display it on my html template. Here is my input html field:

```
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let user of users">
  <div class="col-md-5 mb-2">
      <label>Researcher:</label>
      <input id="createdBy" type="text" class="form-control" 
        [(ngModel)]="screen.createdBy" name="createdBy" 
        required #createdBy="ngModel" 
        placeholder="{{ user.firstName }}" 
        ngValue="user.firstName"
        >
  </div>
```

I use `placeholder` attribute to test to make sure I retrieve the user first name and I do. Placeholder displays it. But I need to display user's first name as a value of the text field just like `asp.net`.

I've tried `ngValue` and `value` attributes but I couldn't get that. `FormsModule` and `BrowserModule` are defined in the `app.module.ts` file. I will be appreciated if you could show me where I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `[(ngModel)]` you are indeed setting the value of the input so if you want to display the `user.firstName` you need to copy that value to `screen.createdBy`.

Comment: `screen.createdBy` should be assigned to `user.firstName`. Basically I should get username from `userService` and display it in the input. Then this
 value should be `screen.createdBy`

Comment: If you retrieve the username from `userService` you should copy that value to `screen.createdBy` in order to display it in the `input`.

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="screen.createdBy"` works in both ways, it displays the value of `screen.createdBy` if it changes, and also stores the value of the `input` if the input changes.